# Unable to get the API result using javascript code

Tags: javascript, azure-api-management

I'm working on `API management` and `exposing API using Javascript code` 
If I go to `Developer portal` and `check my url` it gives me `correct result` like below

```
Response content
[{
"ContactId":1,
"Name":"Debra Garcia",
"Address":"1234 Main St",
},

{"ContactId":2,
"Name":"Thorsten Weinrich",
"Address":"5678 1st Ave W",
}]

but using javascript code I'm not getting anything Nor status error code :(
Js Code
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {

            'subscription-key': 'mykey',
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://mydemo.azure-api.net/marketing/contacts?' + $.param(params),
            type: 'GET',
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where I need to debug?
[image]

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Maybe an XSS problem?

Comment: no error :( what is exactly Cross-Site Scripting issue?

Comment: Use Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), Developer Tools in your Browser (F12 in Chrome and Internet Explorer) or a hosted service like Runscope (https://www.runscope.com/) to act as a debgging proxy to your API.  I would start with your in-browser tools first and use the 'Network' tab to see what response the API HTTP calls return (anything in 400 / 500 response range isn't good).

Comment: @SimonW W thanks After F12 getting 200 status code with no data in request body :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have enabled CORS support on your API using the correct policy.  The [Azure documentation site](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-policy-reference/#cors) has an example of how to do this (snippet below):

```
<cors>
    <allowed-origins>
        <origin>*</origin> <!-- allow any -->
        <!-- OR a list of one or more specific URIs (case-sensitive) -->
        <origin>http://contoso.com:81</origin> <!-- URI must include scheme, host, and port. If port is omitted, 80 is assumed for http and 443 is assumed for https. -->
    </allowed-origins>
</cors>
```

Comment: Where exactly I need to configure :O
I have installed this Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Comment: This policy is added via the Publisher Portal for Azure API Management.